# LWC - Pagination - Stay on Page after edit

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagination

I am using a pagination LWC and I'm trying to figure out how I can stay on the same page after I edit a record.  The structure is in the picture below.

I have a main component with an OppList Component on it.  On the OppList component I have a pagination component, a datatable that takes the results from pagination and I have a editRecord Component.

After I edit a record I want to return to the same page as I started with.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!!

Here are the relevant code snippets:

Main LWC HTML

```
<c-opplist  filteredopps={filteredopps} onclose = {refreshHandler} page-number={pageNumber}></c-opplist>
```

Main LWC Javascript

```
      //triggered from child or grandchild to refresh data form changes on child and grandchild components
      refreshHandler(event){
        //setting this variable (that gets set in the wire) will ensure the wire fires when a record is added/edited
        this.recordsRendered = 1 + this.recordsRendered;
      }
```

OppList HTML

```
    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread" > 
                    <lightning-layout-Item size="12" class= "slds-size_2-of-2">
                        <div class="slds-var-m-vertical_medium">
                            <c-pagination records={filteredopps} onupdate={updateOppHandler}></c-pagination>
                        </div>
                    
                        <template if:true={filteredgroupstructures}>
                            <lightning-datatable
                                    id="pdftable"
                                    data={visibleOpps}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    column-widths-mode={auto}
                                    key-field="Id"
                                    sorted-by={sortBy}
                                    sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                                    onsort={handleSortdata}
                                    onrowaction={handleRowActions}
                                    draft-values={draftValues}
                                    onsave={handleSave}
                                    onerror={handleError}
                                    wrap-text-max-lines=3>
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </template>
                    <template if:true={error}>
                                    {error}
                    </template>
                        </lightning-layout-Item>
                    </lightning-layout>
```

OppList Javascript

```
    //assign one pages worth of Opps to display (pagination)
    updateOppHandler(event){
      this.visibleOpps=[...event.detail.records]
      //reset the variable to determine if we should stay on the page
  }
```

Full Pagination HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread">
                <div class="slds-col"><!--RECORDS PER PAGE-->
                        <div class="slds-list_inline slds-p-bottom_xx-small customSelect">
                            <label class="slds-text-color_weak slds-p-horizontal_x-small" for="recordsPerPage">Records per page:</label> 
                            <div class="slds-select_container">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="recordsPerPage" onchange={handleRecordsPerPage}>
                                    <template for:each={pageSizeOptions} for:item="option">
                                        <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </lightning-layout-item>

        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-button label="Previous"
            icon-name="utility:chevronleft"
            onclick={previousHandler}
            disabled={disablePrevious}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>

        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
         <p class="slds-text-align_center"> Displaying {currentPage} of {totalPage} Page(s) </p>   
         <p class="slds-text-align_center"> Here is Previous Page {previousPage}</p>
         <p class="slds-text-align_center"> stayOnPage is {stayOnPage}</p>
        </lightning-layout-item >

        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-button label="Next"
            icon-name="utility:chevronright"
            icon-position="right"
            onclick={nextHandler}
            disabled={disableNext}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>

    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Full Pagination Javascript

```
import SystemModstamp from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SystemModstamp';
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
const recordsPerPage = [15,25,50,100];

export default class Pagination extends LightningElement {
    totalRecords
    recordSize = 15;
    currentPage = 1;
    totalPage = 0;
    visibleRecords 
      //used to get to same page after editing
    previousPage 
      //passed from parent - should we navigate back to same page on list
    @api stayOnPage 

    @api pageSizeOptions = recordsPerPage; //Page size options; valid values are array of integers

      //setter for records variable passed
    get records(){
        return this.visibleRecords
    }
      //setter for records variable passed - will fire onload of page
    @api 
    set records(data){
        if(data && data.length){
            this.totalRecords = data;
            this.totalPage = Math.ceil(data.length/this.recordSize)
              //call method to fire event to pass records to parent
            this.updateRecords()
        }

    }

    get disablePrevious(){
        return this.currentPage<=1
    }
    get disableNext(){
        return this.currentPage>=this.totalPage
    }

    previousHandler(){
        if(this.currentPage>1){
            this.previousPage = this.currentPage-1
            this.currentPage = this.currentPage-1
            this.updateRecords();
        }
    }

    nextHandler(){

        if(this.currentPage < this.totalPage){
            this.previousPage = this.currentPage+1
            console.log('4 here is nexthandler and prevousPage ' + this.previousPage)
            this.currentPage = this.currentPage+1
            this.updateRecords()
        }
    }
      //method to update the records to display
    updateRecords(){
        if(this.stayOnPage == true){
            this.currentPage = this.previousPage  
        

            if(this.currentPage >this.totalPage){
                this.currentPage = 1
            }
        }

    
        const start = (this.currentPage -1)*this.recordSize
        const end = this.recordSize*this.currentPage
          //create non mutable copy starting at 0 through the record size
        this.visibleRecords = this.totalRecords.slice(start, end)
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('update',{
            detail:{
                records:this.visibleRecords,
                previousPage:this.previousPage
            }
        }))
    }
      //called when the number of records per page field is updated
    handleRecordsPerPage(event){
        this.recordSize = event.target.value;
        this.updateRecords();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Frank - What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried to create a variable called previousPage on the pagination method.  I pass this up to the oppList but that variable gets reset to null. the actual records are populated in a variable using a wire and apex class.  that list of records gets passed to the opplist and is tracked with @api.   When I try to edit a record, I see my wire getting called twice... the first time, my page number is there but the second time, it nulls the page out.  thanks!