# LWC passing Variablle to Child Component

Tags: pagination

I have been struggling to get my pagination to stay on the same page after I edit a record.  I have variables on the parent that track the page number, if a record was just edited and a list of the records to pass to pagination.

I am passing each one of these variables to the pagination component.  I have a method that I call that needs all of these variables.  So currently, my solution isn't working because each getter calls the method that needs all 3 variables.

Does it make sense to create an object variable that has my two string variables and my list variable?  That would allow me to use one setter that fires on the child that can call my method with all three of the variables.

thanks!!!

Comment: Without Minimum Reproducible code (MRC) it will be hard to get answers to this. Please add necessary code samples

Comment: I had posted the detailed question here below.  But since I had not received a reply, I was hoping that someone could just tell me conceptually how to do this. thanks!  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358744/lwc-pagination-stay-on-page-after-edit?noredirect=1#comment522183_358744

Comment: Do review e.g. [Communicate from Child to Parent](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-from-child-to-parent) to conform you are using the right pattern of custom event from child to parent.